# All Tags not working after FTP my website to the server

Tags: channel, tags

After I have FTP my website to the server, none of the tags is working, another word, there is no content pulled from the CMS to the template. My website is http://www.pwshare.co.uk/.

Please take a look and give some advice!

Thank you!
Michael

Comment: What is your EE version? And what is your PHP version?

Comment: Thanks for this, I have just found out the reason why it doesn't work. I am using ExpressionEngine V4 and my server-side PHP was at version 5.6. I have changed it to V7 and it started to work! Thanks again

Comment: As i have expected :)

Answer (score 1):

ExpressionEngine required PHP V7+ which I used PHP 5.6. After updated the PHP version it all started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your channel entry [Parameters](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html) that you have used in expression engine code like channel, disable etc.

If still it is not fixed, then paste your code here. So I can suggest in detail.

Comment: @Michael Lin This does make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chirag, the problem has resolved! I am using EE4 which requires PHP V7+, but my server-side PHP version was V5.6, after I changed it to V7 it starts to work.